# Forsaken Lore expansion for Eldritch Horror: what are the new mysteries for the base game AOO?

Tags: eldritch-horror, eldritch-horror-forsaken-lore, eldritch-horror-strange-remnants

Eldritch Horror is starting to feel a bit same-y for me so I`m thinking of spicing things up with an expansion (one of the small ones, since the big ones are ridiculously expensive for me, at that price - or cheaper -  I can get a whole new game). But anyway, after researching what Forsaken Lore and Strange Remnants offer I incline towards the latter.

However, what Forsaken Lore has and I find **really** interesting is the fact that you get 2 new mysteries for the 4 base-game AOO. This sounds great, because a big part of the repetitive nature of EH for me is the fact that in each game you tackle 3 out of only 4 possible mysteries.

Hence my question: can you please let me know what the 8 mysteries in Forsaken Lore (2 for each base game AOO) do? Photos would be great, but if you think that could raise copyright issues a text description of them would be enough, don`t much care about flavour text. If the new mysteries are interesting enough and feel significantly different than the base game ones I just might get Forsaken Lore for now, even though I find Strange Remnants more attractive (thematically, investigator and AOO-wise). Thanks a lot!

Comment: There's a wonderful [wiki for Arkham Horror](http://www.arkhamhorrorwiki.com/Main_Page) that has the text for each card, but it doesn't look like there is an equivalent for Eldritch Horror unfortunately.

Comment: That does look great! I found a [wiki](http://eldritchhorrorgame.wikia.com/wiki/Eldritch_Horror_Wiki) for EH, but it`s very much a work in progress, just a few general pages for now. It might get better over time though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Azathoth**

> **Voice of Azathoth**
>   When an investigator would gain an Artifact, he may gain the Massa di Requiem per Shuggay Artifact instead.
>
> At the end of the Mythos Phase, an investigator may spend Clues equal to `[Number of Players]` and discard the Massa di requiem per Shuggay Artifact to solve this Mystery.
>
> **The Green Flame**
>
> When this card enters play, spawn the Tulzscha Epic Monster on a random space.
>
> At the end of Mythos Phase, if the Tulzscha Epic Monster has been defeated, solve this mystery.
>   *Additional info: At each reckoning, Tulzscha adds 1 Eldritch token to the omen track.*

**Cthulhu**

> **Queen of the Deep Ones**
>   When this card enters play, spawn the Hydra Epic Monster on space 8.
>
> When an investigator would gain an Artifact, he may gain the Sword of Y'ha-Talla Artifact instead.
>
> At the end of Mythos Phase, if the Hydra Epic Monster has been defeated, solve this mystery.
>   *Additional info: Hydra can't be damaged without the Sword of Y'ha-Talla.*
>
> **Threatening Seas**
>   When this card enters play, each investigator places 1 Eldritch token on the nearest Sea space that does not contain an Eldritch token.
>
> As an encounter, an investigator on a space containing an Eldritch token may attempt to prolong Cthulhu's slumber (`[Lore]`-1). If he passes, he may spend 1 Clue and discard 1 Spell to place that Eldritch token on this card.
>
> At the end of the Mythos Phase, if there are Eldritch tokens on this card equal to `[Number of Players]`, solve this Mystery. Do not discard the Eldritch tokens from the game board.

**Yog-Sothoth**

> **The Stone Circles**
>   When this card enters play, place a number of Eldritch tokens equal to half `[Number of Players]` each on a random space.
>
> As an encounter, an investigator on a space containing an Eldritch token may attempt to disrupt the ritual (`[Lore]`-1). If he passes, he may spend 2 Clues to place that Eldritch token on this card. If he fails, a Cultist Monster ambushes him!
>
> At the end of the Mythos Phase, if there are Eldritch tokens on this card equal to half `[Number of Players]`, solve this Mystery.
>
> **Void Between Worlds**
>   As an encounter, an investigator on a space containing a Gate may travel to the void between worlds by drawing and resolving a Void Between Worlds Special Encounter.
>
> At the end of the Mythos Phase, if there are Eldritch tokens on this card equal to half `[Number of Players]`, solve this Mystery.
>   *Additional info: These encounters are a harder version of Other World encounters. A successful encounter allows to both close the gate and put an eldritch token on the Mystery.*

**Shub-Niggurath**

> **Blasphemy of the Black Goat**
>   When this card enters play, spawn the Yeb Epic Monster on space 19.
>
> At the end of Mythos Phase, if the Yeb Epic Monster has been defeated, solve this mystery.
>   *Additional info: When spawned, Yeb spawns 2 additional monsters on it's space.*
>
> **Hour of the Moon Lens**
>   When this card enters play, place the Mystery token in London.
>
> As an encounter, an investigator on London may watch a ritual that transforms the worshipers of Shub-Niggurath into goat spawn; a Goat Spawn Monster ambushes him! If he defeats it, he may spend 2 Clues to place 1 Eldritch token on this card.
>
> At the end of the Mythos Phase, if there are Eldritch tokens on this card equal to half `[Number of Players]`, solve this Mystery.

Comment: This is great info! And you wrote all this from memory? You must play the game a lot :)) I have to say most of them sound really cool. I'll mark the question as solved but if and when you can provide more detail from the cards themselves it would be vey welcome. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'll definitely do, but probably as late as in the second week of May.  
Right now I don't even have internet at my house.

Answer (score 0):

> With six unique Mysteries, and a host of Epic Monsters, Yig will prove a challenging adversary to even the most courageous and cunning of Investigators.
>
> Investigators can now uncover new arcane mysteries unique to each Ancient One with the Forsaken Lore expansion

[image]

[Fantasy Flight's Site news/2014/11/7/](https://www.fantasyflightgames.com/en/news/2014/2/10/forsaken-lore/)

> Fantasy Flight Games is proud to announce Forsaken Lore, an expansion for Eldritch Horror. Forsaken Lore adds over two hundred new cards to Eldritch Horror, including over one hundred new Encounter cards, twenty-four condition cards, and fourteen new mysteries.
>
> Yig enters the game with six unique mysteries, and your Investigators will need to gather all of their strength and cunning to keep Yig from entering our world. Break the power of the Serpent Crown over the will of the people, and defeat the Winged Serpent Epic Monster in order to world safe once more.

[Fantasy Flight news/2014/2/10/](https://www.fantasyflightgames.com/en/news/2014/2/10/forsaken-lore/)

Ok so There are 14 new mysteries, 6 for the new AOO **Yig** and 2 each for the four original AOO. Hopefully this will motivate an owner to come back with further details. I'm not sure but I think the one that you can read in my picture is for Yig.

I didn't see anything myself but your best bet is probably the [Wiki](http://eldritchhorrorgame.wikia.com/wiki/Eldritch_Horror_Wiki)

Comment: Exactly, what I am interested in are details about those '2 mysteries each for the four original AOO' that they mention. I also believe the pictured mystery is for Yig, since he`s all about serpents and serpent people. Nothing helpful on that Wiki either...